# Cypress fails to load a website with ENOTFOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, automated-tests, cypress

I have a bunch of cypress tests written. They were all working just fine. But somehow they all started to fail to visit the target site with the following error:

```
cy.visit() failed trying to load:

https://mywebsite.com/accounts/login/

We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.

We received this error at the network level:

  > Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mywebsite.com
```

When I open `https://mywebsite.com/accounts/login/` explicitly in the browser, it opens. So what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Closing cypress browser window, rerunning `npx cypress open` and then starting cypress test worked!!! Though I don't know what might have gone wrong exactly.